# Solidity Error: Doc tag @notice not valid for statements

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, bug

I'm trying to compile my Solidity smart contract, but I keep getting this error:
`Doc tag @notice not valid for statements`.

There is no `@notice` statement in my code. The error seems to happen with Solidity versions from 0.4 to 0.4.9, with and without optimization.

**EDIT:** Through divide and conquer I could attribute the error to the following function:

```
function f(uint blockNumber, bool finalBlock) returns (bool) {
    if (msg.sender != protocolParameters.A)
        return false; // caller is not Alice

    if (blockNumber > protocolValues.blockNumber && blockNumber <= protocolParameters.numberOfBlocks*2) {
        protocolValues.stageNumber = blockNumber*2;

    } else {
        throw; // TODO: is throw angemessen here?
    }
    /// TODO: careful 
    if (finalBlock) {
        protocolValues.phaseNumber = 2; // we go to the TERMINAL phase
        setPayoffs(protocolParameters.DA, protocolParameters.DB + protocolParameters.FV);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I doubt you'll get a satisfactory answer without showing the offending code. Try to pull out everything that you want to hide, but that still exhibits the problem. This type of question is nearly impossible to answer without code, and just from reading the error message, it appears to be a simple matter of bad syntax as opposed to a compiler bug.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush: Done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was the following:

```
/// TODO: careful
```

Apparently `///` is treated specially by the Solidity compiler and lead to the error.

Removing it fixed the issue.

comments added with `/** my comment */` also lead to the error. Notice the double asterisk at the start of the comment